# How to remove class from button when another button is clicked using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, class, toggle

I am having difficulty getting this to work.

I have a responsive tab/accordion. However when clicking on one button, the class "active" is applied, but when clicking another button the "active" class still remains on the previous button. I have to achieve this using Javascript and not jQuery.

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement."

Here is my code at the moment:

```
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var activeAccordion = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {

  accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

    this.classList.toggle("active");
    activeAccordion.classList.remove("active");

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
     if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }) 
}
```

Comment: `activeAccordion` is a _nodelist_ and doesn't have it's own `classList` method. So you need to iterate over all the nodes in that list removing the class.

Comment: activeAccordion in your loop is a list of elements, try activeAccordion[0].classList.remove("active");

Comment: Still does the same thing with the solution above, other accordion/tabs are still staying open when another one is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
activeAccordion.classList.remove("active");
```

by

```
activeAccordion.classList.removeClass("active");
```

Comment: unfortunately this produces the same error as above

Comment: Ok my bad! But i guess try adding the remove line on top of addclass line